# Difference between creating index on a prefix of a string column or the whole column if the actual content length is very limited

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

Assume there is a column `A` of type `varchar(255)` and the actual length of content of this column is about 20 characters for all rows.  Is there any difference between creating index on the whole `A` column or a 20-character prefix of the `A` column, regarding mysql's performance (time and space)?  (The storage engine being InnoDB.)

Answer (score 0):

Speed:

In almost all cases, the index on the 'whole' column is more useful.  In some cases, the Optimizer will ignore a "prefix" index, thereby really making it useless.

Space:

Nothing you mentioned will change the space requirement by much.

Compromise:

What is the max length?  That is, can "255" be decreased?